# cgdb doesn't exit: determining why and fixing

Tags: macos, cgdb

After I run a program through `cgdb`, `cgdb` won't exit. Typing `kill`, then `quit` results in `cgdb` hanging.

If I do not load a file in the debugger, `quit` works. If I load a file but do not run it, `quit` works. If I `run` the file, `quit` hangs.

How do I:

- **Determine why** this is happening? I can't look at the return value of `cgdb` (because I have to `ps aux ; kill` it, or close the `terminal` window, etc). I can't find any references to other people with this issue online, either.
- **Fix it**? Without knowing exactly what's going wrong, is there any `super-cool-command` I can run to force-kill the debugger on `quit`?

Further details:

- Installed `cgdb` with `macports`. Running `port upgrade outdated` has not resolved this issue.
- `cgdb --version` returns: `CGDB 0.6.6`
- `uname -a`: Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0
- Using `OS X 10.8.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is fixed in cgdb-0.6.7. Here's the issue: https://github.com/cgdb/cgdb/issues/1

Homebrew has the latest cgdb in it, or you could compile from source.

Comment: Thanks. `cgdb-0.6.7` hasn't made it into `macports` yet, apparently.